# How to run the same query on all tables in Access Database?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

All tables have the same structure the same column names.

Here is a code:

`UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN TableX ON Table1.Column1= TableX.Column1
SET Table1.Column2 = TableX.Column2`

But I would like to run this code on all tables: Table2, Table3, Table4....Table30

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, please provide desired output. and perhaps explain why your query doesn't work?

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: For example there are 50 tables. Each table contains an identical column name called ColumnName_X an I want to display all values from it.

Comment: In MS Access using MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood well, that's it works for you ...

```
SELECT AllTables.*
FROM AllTables
WHERE AllTables.ColumnName_X = AllTables.ColumnName_Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT ColumnName_X
FROM table1
WHERE .....
UNION ALL
SELECT ColumnName_X
FROM table2
WHERE .....
```

As per my comment, your requirement is not clear.

Comment: SELECT Column1
FROM  UNION ALL (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4)
WHERE Column1= Column2 Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @DemenyiNorbert that is not possible. you best bet is doing it as I explained.

Comment: @DemenyiNorbert where is `Column2` coming from? same table?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here assume SQL server - that's not a tag no part of this question and will not work.

if your tables are named table1 to table30, then this should work:

```
Dim strSQL       As String
Dim i            As Integer
Dim strTable     As String

For i = 1 To 10
   strTable = "Table" & i
   strSQL = "update " & strTable & _
            " inner join TableX on " & strTable & ".column1 = TableX.Column1" & _
           " SET " & strTable & ".Column2 = TaxbleX.Column2"
 Debug.Print strSQL

 CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

Next i
```

Answer (score -1):

use the following query to get a list of tables and its schema containing particular column(ColumnX)

```
SELECT
  sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
  sys.tables.name AS TableName,
  schema_name (sys.tables.schema_Id) as schemaName
FROM
  sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
  sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
WHERE
  sys.columns.name = 'ColumnName' 
  --and schema_name (sys.tables.schema_Id) = 'schemaName'
```

output:(if columnX is ID)

```
ColumnName  TableName   schemaName
ID          MusicApp    dbo
id          employ      dbo
```

to get values of ID, you can store above queries output in #temptable and use loop to fetch dynamically

```
declare @tablename varchar(max)= ''
 declare @count int = 1
 declare @tablecount int= (select count(*) from #temptable)
 while(@count <= @tablecount)
 begin
 set @tablename = (select tablename from #temptable where seqid = @count)
exec ( 'select id from '+@tablename+' ')
set @count = @count + 1
end
```

hope this helps you :)

Comment: I would like to do some like this: 
SELECT Column1 FROM UNION ALL (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4) WHERE Column1= Column2         or      SELECT Column1 FROM sys.tables WHERE Column1= Column2